# What's holding DS9 at the wormhole entrance?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In "Emissary," the station DS9 is moved from orbit around Bajor to the entrance of the wormhole- but without any stellar body there for it to orbit, what's keeping the station from drifting away?

Comment: https://m0vie.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/tos-whomournsforadonais2.jpg

Answer (score 27):

Both the wormhole and Deep Space Nine are in orbit of Bajor-B'Hava'el, the central star in the [Bajoran Star System](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran_system). The station has thrusters that allow it to make small corrections and remain in constant proximity to the wormhole itself.

[image]
**<sub><sup>Map Courtesy of the [Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Technical_Manual)</sup></sub>**

---

The [original script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/402.txt) for [DS9: Emissary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emissary_(episode)) indicates that the station has been moved about 160 million kilometres from its original position (which, for reference is about 80% of the mean distance between Earth and Mars). Its new location is still well within the same star system.

> **O'BRIEN:** *This isn't a starship, Major. We've got six working thrusters to power us and that's it. A hundred-sixty million kilometer
> trip would take two months.*
>
> **KIRA:** *It's got to be there tomorrow.*